# How safe is an AppDomain sandboxed with SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution?

Tags: c#, appdomain, sandbox, dynamic-compilation

I have a plug-in vector established using System.AddIn that accepts the body of a pre-defined method, munges the method body into boilerplate code, generates the assembly and executes the method.

The assembly references `System` and `System.Core` and is sandboxed with

```
var pset = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
pset.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
```

The only exception I can find reference to that could possible bring down the host is a stack overflow, which could be invoked any number of creative means, e.g. closing the body and declaring a recursive method etc...

And then there are the possible attack vectors exposed by the referenced assemblies, `System` and `System.Core`.

My question is: How safe is this and what are some examples of malicious code that could potentially bring down the host and possible ways to prevent such attacks?

UPDATE: also for those familiar with the Managed AddIn Framework, apply the same question to `AddInSecurityLevel.Internet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It usually isn't hard for an add-in to bomb the host.  All it has to do is start a thread and make it throw an unhandled exception.  Jesse Kaplan [has blogged](http://blogs.msdn.com/clraddins/archive/2007/05/01/using-appdomain-isolation-to-detect-add-in-failures-jesse-kaplan.aspx) about a possible counter-measure for those kind of failures.  Sandboxing was covered by Shawn Farkas in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/08/08/449050.aspx).